# How to remove duplicate elements from an array with complexity O(n),

Tags: java, data-structures

```
int [] ar = {4,5,6,2,3,2};

for (int i  = 0 ; i < ar.length ; i ++)
{   
    if (ar[Math.abs(ar[i])] >= 0 )
        ar[Math.abs(ar[i])] = -ar[Math.abs(ar[i])];
    else
        System.out.println(ar[i]);      
}
```

This is not giving me exact answer.

Also, none of the current available answer is relevant.

Comment: What were you expecting `ar[ar[x]]` to accomplish? The values are not array indexes. --- For a solution with complexity _O(n)_, use a `HashSet<Integer>`. Alternatively, if values are bound to a limited range, use a `boolean[]` where the value *are* indexes into the array.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(ar).distinct().forEach(System.out::println)` guarantees linear time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Integer [] ar = {4,5,6,2,3,2, 5, 7, 8, 5, 3, 2, 2};
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ar));

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> seenBefore = new HashMap<>();
    //go through the array and determine the repeats
    for (int i  = 0 ; i < ar.length ; i ++)
    {   
       if(seenBefore.containsKey(ar[i]))
       {
           Integer count = seenBefore.get(ar[i]);
           count++;
           seenBefore.put(ar[i], count);
       }
       else{
           seenBefore.put(ar[i], 1);
       }
    }
    //now get ride of the repeats
    for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
    {
        if(seenBefore.containsKey(ar[i]) && seenBefore.get(ar[i]) > 1)
        {
            list.remove(new Integer(ar[i]));
            seenBefore.put(ar[i], seenBefore.get(ar[i]) - 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Since we have two for loops that loop based on the length of the array our big O complexity is O(2n) which is O(n)